# How to make a legend in the scipy dendrogram

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, scipy

I want to make a legend for a scipy dendrogram. I have tried to find hexadecimal color in the dendrogram function, but I didn't find anything. How to do this?

This is the code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_score
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram, linkage

 .......

# Agglomerative Clustering di sklearn
agg_clustering = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=4).fit(dfx_scaled)

# Aggiunta della colonna "clusters"
dfx['clusters'] = agg_clustering.labels_

# plot del dendogramma
linkage_matrix = linkage(dfx_scaled, 'ward')
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))
dendrogram(linkage_matrix,no_labels=True )
d = dendrogram(linkage_matrix,no_labels=True )
plt.axhline(y=140, color='black', linestyle='--')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you add some reproducible test data? Perhaps [this tutorial](https://joernhees.de/blog/2015/08/26/scipy-hierarchical-clustering-and-dendrogram-tutorial/) gives some inspiration? Can you describe the kind of legend you need? Maybe add an image? Did you look at related StackOverflow questions?

Comment: @JohanC you can make random noise as dataset. I want a classic lengend with color+label. The question is: where the dendrogram function take the colors palette. This function dont use the base colors as matplotlib, but a particular colors palette.

Comment: I can't create a suitable random dataeset without knowing how your data looks like and what exactly you mean by colors. It is still very unclear which labels you want in the legend.  Did you try `hierarchy.set_link_color_palette(...)` as mentioned in the [dendogram docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram.html)?  Did you consider seaborn's `sns.clustermap`?  Can **you** [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75481541/edit) some reproducible test data?  If you don't want your question answered, it would be better to delete it.